# Change DotsPageIndicator position programmatically

Tags: android

I made one `GridView` with `DotsPageIndicator`.

```
private GridViewPager pager;
private DotsPageIndicator dotsPageIndicator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste);
    pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new GridPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
    dotsPageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
    dotsPageIndicator.setDotFadeWhenIdle(false);
    dotsPageIndicator.setPager(pager);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When I use `notifyDataSetChanged()` the position of dots is lost and it returns to the first. How can I change dots position programmatically?

Comment: I think dotsPageIndicator provide property to set position!

Comment: @NiravRanpara how?